Aligning the Summary Statistics and Correlation Matrix
I am trying to create a table in LaTeX that displays summary statistics and a correlation matrix, similar to the table shown below. However, I am encountering some issues with formatting and aligning the correlation matrix correctly. Could someone please help me with the correct LaTeX code to achieve this?
Here is an image of the table I am trying to replicate:

my output :

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[htbp]\centering
\caption{Summary statistics and correlation matrix}
\begin{threeparttable}
\begin{tabular}{lcccccc}
\toprule
                    & \multicolumn{1}{c}{N} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Mean} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Std. Dev.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Min.} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{Max.} \\
\midrule
Gross Savings/GNI            & 1338 & 20.29 & 8.57 & -33.04 & 54.23 \\
Genuine Saving/GNI           & 1158 & 8.24 & 11.71 & -54.89 & 44.32 \\
GNI per capita (ln)          & 1338 & 7.98 & 1.46 & 4.70 & 10.69 \\
GDP growth (lagged one year) & 1338 & 3.40 & 4.09 & -13.38 & 33.99 \\
Age-dependency               & 1338 & 0.65 & 0.17 & 0.37 & 1.17 \\
Urbanisation                 & 1338 & 60.72 & 21.98 & 10.01 & 100 \\
Resource exports             & 1338 & 21.99 & 26.85 & 0.02 & 99.70 \\
Lack of corruption           & 1206 & 3.54 & 1.37 & 0 & 6 \\
Bureaucratic quality         & 1338 & 3.87 & 1.45 & 1 & 6 \\
Rule of law                  & 1338 & 3.95 & 1.53 & 0 & 6 \\
\midrule
                             & I    & II   & III  & IV   & V    & VI   & VII  & VIII & IX   & X    \\
\midrule
I: Gross Savings/GNI         & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
II: Genuine Saving/GNI       & 0.59 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
III: GNI per capita (ln)     & 0.33 & 0.19 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
IV: GDP growth               & 0.24 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
V: Age-dependency            &-0.47 &-0.34 &-0.57 &-0.09 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      \\
VI: Urbanisation             & 0.20 & 0.01 & 0.62 & 0.26 &-0.60 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      \\
VII: Resource exports        &-0.05 & 0.06 &-0.09 & 0.01 & 0.10 & 0.07 & 1.00 &      &      &      \\
VIII: Lack of corruption     & 0.02 & 0.34 & 0.27 & 0.18 &-0.38 & 0.48 &-0.30 & 1.00 &      &      \\
IX: Bureaucratic quality     & 0.26 & 0.44 & 0.43 & 0.11 &-0.55 & 0.52 &-0.41 & 0.54 & 1.00 &      \\
X: Rule of law               & 0.28 & 0.18 & 0.47 & 0.17 &-0.57 & 0.46 &-0.41 & 0.52 & 0.70 & 1.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end{table}

\end{document}



I can't see a compelling reason for aligning the 5 data columns of the first table with the 10 data columns of the second table. I'd rather create two separate tabular environments. Of course, it's ok to embed both tabular environments in a single table environment.
I do suggest you employ the S column type of the siunitx package to align the numbers in the data columns on their respective explicit or implicit decimal markers. This will be especially important for the correlation matrix table.
A separate comment: Unless your paper size is unusually large and/or the margins are quite narrow, I think it'll be necessary to render the table in landscape mode.

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}   % for well-spaced horizontal rules
\usepackage{pdflscape}  % for 'landscape' environment
\usepackage{siunitx}    % for 'S' column type
\newcolumntype{T}[1]{S[table-format=#1]}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}

\centering
\caption{Summary statistics and correlation matrix}

\medskip
\begin{tabular}{@{} l T{4.0} T{2.2} T{2.2} T{2.2} T{2.2} @{}}
\toprule
Variable & {$N$} & {Mean} & {St.Dev.} & {Min.} & {Max.} \\
\midrule
Gross Savings/GNI            & 1338 & 20.29 &  8.57 & -33.04 &  54.23 \\
Genuine Saving/GNI           & 1158 &  8.24 & 11.71 & -54.89 &  44.32 \\
GNI per capita (ln)          & 1338 &  7.98 &  1.46 &   4.70 &  10.69 \\
GDP growth (lagged one year) & 1338 &  3.40 &  4.09 & -13.38 &  33.99 \\
Age-dependency               & 1338 &  0.65 &  0.17 &.  0.37 &   1.17 \\
\addlinespace
Urbanisation                 & 1338 & 60.72 & 21.98 &  10.01 & 100.00 \\
Resource exports             & 1338 & 21.99 & 26.85 &   0.02 & 99.70 \\
Lack of corruption           & 1206 &  3.54 &  1.37 &   0 & 6 \\
Bureaucratic quality         & 1338 &  3.87 &  1.45 &   1 & 6 \\
Rule of law                  & 1338 &  3.95 &  1.53 &   0 & 6 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{@{} r l *{10}{T{-1.2}} @{}}
\toprule
& Variable & {I} & {II} & {III} & {IV} & {V} & {VI} & {VII} & {VIII} & {IX} & {X}  \\
\midrule
I &  Gross Savings/GNI         & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
II &  Genuine Saving/GNI       & 0.59 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
III &  GNI per capita (ln)     & 0.33 & 0.19 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
IV &  GDP growth               & 0.24 & 0.15 & 0.07 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      &      \\
V &  Age-dependency            &-0.47 &-0.34 &-0.57 &-0.09 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      &      \\
\addlinespace
VI &  Urbanisation             & 0.20 & 0.01 & 0.62 & 0.26 &-0.60 & 1.00 &      &      &      &      \\
VII &  Resource exports        &-0.05 & 0.06 &-0.09 & 0.01 & 0.10 & 0.07 & 1.00 &      &      &      \\
VIII &  Lack of corruption     & 0.02 & 0.34 & 0.27 & 0.18 &-0.38 & 0.48 &-0.30 & 1.00 &      &      \\
IX &  Bureaucratic quality     & 0.26 & 0.44 & 0.43 & 0.11 &-0.55 & 0.52 &-0.41 & 0.54 & 1.00 &      \\
X &  Rule of law               & 0.28 & 0.18 & 0.47 & 0.17 &-0.57 & 0.46 &-0.41 & 0.52 & 0.70 & 1.00 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{table}
\end{landscape}

\end{document}

